# How can I Install Ubuntu 12.04 for an AMD processor?

Tags: 12.04, installation

When I install Ubuntu, do I have to type any codes?

Comment: It basically has a Great Graphical User interface for installing , no codes at all. Just try it from Live Media and get to know more it before installing

Comment: your question 's title and the question you are asking do not seem to match... what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

By code if you mean product keys like windows then answer is no.

Ubuntu is completely free of charge. You don't need any product code. You can download it, burn a disc or create a live USB (using appropriate software) and install it. Even before installing you can select **Try Ubuntu** to run it directly from the live CD/DVD/USB.

Answer (score 1):

There are no codes or keys required to install Ubuntu.

Installation is especially easy with the installer provided for Windows on [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com), known as the Wubi installer. While an installation from Wubi will prevent hibernation (suspend works just as well in my opinion) and has some very minor read/write hindrances, it allows you to easily install and uninstall Ubuntu without all of the complications and possible dangers of partitioning.